# How to style a label when input inside it is checked?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, styled-components

Right [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-with-pseudo-class-on-input-forked-07dju) I've a code where I change the label's background when input is checked, but label is right after the input, as displayed in the following example.

```js
const Label = styled.label`
  background: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  &:checked + ${Label} {
    background: blue;
  }
`;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Input id="input" type="checkbox" />
    <Label for="input" />
  </div>
);
```

But how would it be possible to change the label background if the input was inside the label? as displayed in the example below:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Label for="input" />
       <Input id="input" type="checkbox" />
    </Label>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `bubbling stage` in css like also `styled-components`. But you can get event from `input` and then pass in `styled-component`. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fire-b2u3e?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Label = styled.label`
  background: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? "blue" : "red")};
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  /* &:checked + ${Label} {
    background: blue;
  } */
`;

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setChecked(!checked);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Label for="input" checked={checked}>
        <Input id="input" type="checkbox" onChange={toggle} />
      </Label>
    </div>
  );
}
```